# Converting FieldInfo value to a List When List type not known

Tags: c#, list, reflection, system.reflection

I have the following:

```
    [Serializable()]
    public struct ModuleStruct {
        public string moduleId;
        public bool isActive;
        public bool hasFrenchVersion;
        public string titleEn;
        public string titleFr;
        public string descriptionEn;
        public string descriptionFr;
        public bool isLoaded;
        public List<SectionStruct> sections;
        public List<QuestionStruct> questions;
    }
```

I create an instance of this and populate it (contents not relevant for question). I have a function which takes the instantiated object as one parameter, lets call it module, and the type of this object as the other parameter: `module.GetType()`.

This function will then, using reflection, and:

```
    FieldInfo[] fields = StructType.GetFields();
    string fieldName = string.Empty;
```

The parameter names in the function are `Struct` and `StructType`.

I loop through the field names within `Struct`, pull the values and of the different fields and do something with it. All is well until I get to:

```
    public List<SectionStruct> sections;
    public List<QuestionStruct> questions;
```

The function only knows the type of `Struct` by `StructType`. In VB, the code is simply:

```
    Dim fieldValue = Nothing
    fieldValue = fields(8).GetValue(Struct)
```

and then:

```
    fieldValue(0)
```

to get the first element in the list sections; however, in C#, the same code does not work because `fieldValue` is an object and I cannot do `fieldValue[0]` on an object.

My question, then, is given that the function only knows the type of `Struct` by `StructType`, how do I replicate the VB behaviour in C#, if it is even possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the first object in the of the `sections` list, knowing that it is a `List<SectionStruct>`?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know that the type is SectionStruct when trying to get the first element. If I knew what it was, it'd be easy. Like I say, in VB it's super easy because it automatically treats it like the underlying type. C# doesn't, so I need to figure out how to have it handled like the underlying type.

Comment: But you **DO** know it. Just not at compile-time ;) Let me fix some example code for you, and at the same time, teach you some [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002(v=vs.100).aspx)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some (very simple) example code that's pretty much spelled out... I really don't want to do the whole thing for you, because this could be a great lesson in reflection :)

```
private void DoSomethingWithFields<T>(T obj)
{
    // Go through all fields of the type.
    foreach (var field in typeof(T).GetFields())
    {
        var fieldValue = field.GetValue(obj);

        // You would probably need to do a null check
        // somewhere to avoid a NullReferenceException.

        // Check if this is a list/array
        if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType))
        {
            // By now, we know that this is assignable from IList, so we can safely cast it.
            foreach (var item in fieldValue as IList)
            {
                // Do you want to know the item type?
                var itemType = item.GetType();

                // Do what you want with the items.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // This is not a list, do something with value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A million thank-yous @khellang. A valuable lesson indeed, and so simple. I feel quite dim, but happy.

Comment: Great that you got it working! I guess that transitioning from VB.NET to C# is tougher that you'd expect ;)