# Init a List<T> from GridView DataSource with Reflection for the type

Tags: c#, list, system.reflection

I have a simple question but I'm on it since this morning...

How can I init a `List<T>` without to know its type ? Or (maybe it's more simple) Can I do an `OrderBy` on a `GridView.DataSource` ?

Here my code at this moment :

```
Type type = (from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
             from item in asm.GetTypes() 
             where item.IsClass && item.Name.Equals(myType) 
             select item).Single();
PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(myProperty);

this.DataSource = ((List<object>)this.DataSource)
                  .ConvertAll(item => Convert.ChangeType(item, type))
                  .OrderBy(item => type.InvokeMember(property.Name, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, item, null));
```

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Edit : Maybe I need to tell you that the first cast `(List<object>)this.DataSource` fails and I need something for write `(List<myType>)this.DataSource` instead.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519910/converting-fieldinfo-value-to-a-list-when-list-type-not-known?rq=1

Comment: Thanks but no, it's not the good thing in my case. I need a way to make an orderBy on a `List<myType>` but using reflection for init this list.

Comment: How is `this.DataSource` defined?

Comment: It's a custom GridView, the DataSource is the BaseDataBoundControl of this gridView instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are implementing `IConvertible` for the `item`'s type, this should work:

```
this.DataSource = ((IEnumerable<object>)this.DataSource).ToList()
    .ConvertAll(item => Convert.ChangeType(item, type))
    .OrderBy(item => property.GetValue(item));
```

Comment: You're a genius ! Thanks a lot ! I'm horrified to have spent all this time for just change `List` to `IEnumerable`...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to Alex Filipovici's would be using a generic method and expression:

```
public class Shadam
{
    object DataSource { get; set; }
    public void OrderList(string myType, string myProperty)
    {
        Type type = (from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                     from item in asm.GetTypes()
                     where item.IsClass && item.Name.Equals(myType)
                     select item).Single();

        var property = type.GetProperty(myProperty);
        typeof(Shadam).GetMethod("OrderGenericList")
                      .MakeGenericMethod(type, property.PropertyType)
                      .Invoke(this, new[] { property });
    }

    public void OrderGenericList<T, TProperty>(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var tParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var orderExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TProperty>>(
                                  Expression.Property(tParameter, property),
                                  tParameter
                              ).Compile();

        this.DataSource = ((List<T>)this.DataSource).OrderBy(orderExpression);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this method works too but it's more complicated to establish ^^

Comment: It is a bit more involved, but you get the advantage of type safety. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not easier to order the list before assigning the datasourde? Or using GridView.Sort?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort.aspx

Comment: I do this on the OnSorting event, it's for a custom gridview and i want to sort it for any type is in with just a property as string for to know the type is in and another string raised on the sortExpression for know on what property of my object I need to sort.